# Respond when page orientation change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the below function for the window resize. My question is how do I make it work on window resize as well as page orientation is changed?

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if(this.ab) clearTimeout(this.ab);
        this.ab = setTimeout(function() { 
            $(this).trigger('winresized');
        },1000);
    });
    $(window).on('winresized', function() {

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of resize and [orientationchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange) event:

```
$(window).on("resize orientationchange", function() {
    // Fires on both resize & orientation change
    if(this.ab) clearTimeout(this.ab);
    this.ab = setTimeout(function() { 
        $(this).trigger('winresized');
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: thanks. So `$(window).resize(function() {` needs to be updated to `$(window).on("resize orientationchange", function() {` ?. and the rest remains the same? Is that what you've said in your answer?

Comment: Yup, exactly. That will trigger the `winresized` event for both

Comment: Yep.. I did test it while waiting for your reply. it works - brilliant. thanks :)

Comment: One more thing to add. How do I also write the above using window.addEventListener ?

Comment: `window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {});` - note though that you can't add multiple events like `"resize orientationchange"` - you need to make multiple `addEventListener` calls

Comment: thanks again. So `$(window).on("resize orientationchange", function() {` should be replaced with `window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {` ? Is that it?

Comment: Exactly. Likewise `window.addEventListener("resize", function() {});`

Comment: I came across [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996726/will-window-resize-fire-on-orientation-change). He says using `window.addEventListener("resize", function() {` is more secure? Any ideas on that?